# Code doesn't create files when run in CronJob

Tags: go, cron

I'm trying to create a CronJob that is creating a file and writing some string to it. The Code does work when run as normal go code. Also the code itself is executed when run as a Cronjob (I checked /var/log/syslog and let Print something with „fmt.Print("some string"))
The Problem is that the file I want to create is not created when the Cronjob is executed (I'm root on my Server so „crontab -e” should have enough permissions shouldn't it?)

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "fmt"   
    "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
```

)

```
func main() {

absPath, err := filepath.Abs("loggy.txt")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("Error\n")
}


file, err := os.OpenFile(absPath, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("Error\n")
}


var loggy logrus.Logger
loggy.Out = file
loggy.Level = logrus.DebugLevel
formatter := &logrus.TextFormatter{}
formatter.ForceColors = true
formatter.FullTimestamp = true
loggy.Formatter = formatter

loggy.Warn("Test")

}
```

crontab -e:

```
*/01   *  *  *  * /root/PathToFile/CronJob/./CronJob
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you know the file is not created. Maybe it actually _is_ created, but not where you think...

Comment: man you're right - thanks a lot
Everything has been created under „/root/"
I thougt making the path absolut would help (adjusted the actual code)

Answer (score 0):

So go adjusts the current directory to the directory of crontab when being executed in a Cronjob or the other way round regardingly

Comment: Go doesn't "adjust" anything, it starts in the working directory provided.